# Defining pages by custom variable, reporting to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, meta-tags

Does anyone know how I could add some information to my page (whether in a meta tag or some other way) to indicate to Google Analytics that a page is targeted to a certain segment?

This is pretty straightforward on my main site where everything is set up in hierarchy by target user so I can just use the URL to filter the data.

However for my subdomains, its  a flat structure that's just a bunch of landing and conversion pages so I can't use the URL.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can choose from, but i think the simplest way in your case is to create a "fake" URL for each page. This URL will show in analytics instead of the actual URL.

Add this line to each page (inside the main analytics code)

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/my_segment/page']);
```

If you're using universal analytics you can also specify page title:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': '/my_segment/page',
  'title': 'Segment name'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need something like google affinity groups
take a look to this two links
http://www.google.com/think/products/affinity-segments.html

and

https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2497941

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about what this is and why it helps OP?

Comment: While these links may help answer the question, a high quality answer provides more than just links.  It is better to include the relevant information here directly.  Users shouldn't have to click to understand your answer.   In addition, links may change or break over time.